# Liquibase changeSet with failOnError="false" are always ran?

Tags: sql, database-schema, database-migration, liquibase

I'm trying to execute the following `changeSet` in liquibase which should create an index. If the index doesn't exist, it should silently fail:

```
<changeSet failOnError="false" author="sys" id="1">
    <createIndex unique="true"  indexName="key1" tableName="Table1">
        <column name="name" />
    </createIndex>
</changeSet>
```

So far, so good. The Problem is, that this `changeSet` doesn't get logged into DATABASECHANGELOG table and is therefor executed every time liquibase runs. According to the liquibase documentation and e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625567/prevent-error-when-dropping-not-existing-sequences-creating-existing-users#answer-1627524) from Nathen Voxland i thought that the changeset should be marked as ran in the DATABASECHANGELOG table. Instead it isn't logged at all and as i said before executed every time liquibase runs (and fails everytime again).

Am i missing something?

(I'm using MySQL as DBMS)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625567/prevent-error-when-dropping-not-existing-sequences-creating-existing-users#answer-1627524) given by Nathen Voxland, he recommended the more correct approach of using a [precondition](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/preconditions.html) to check the state of the database, before running the changeset.

It seems to me that ignoring a failure is a bad idea.... Means you don't fully control the database configuration.... The "failOnError" parameter allows liquibase to continue. Wouldn't it be a bad idea for a build to record a changset as executed, if in fact it didn't because an error occurred?

Comment: I'm totally with you, using a precondition is the right approach in my opinion too. After all, that's what i did with my `changeSet` (although uniqueConstraintExists precondition is missing, but that's another fact). I just stumbled upon my expectations of the `failOnError="false"` attribute and I asked myself if the described behavior is a bug or a feature ;)

Comment: Unfortunately a precondition for Oracle non-null doesn't work for me because checking for a non-nullable column isn't supported by liquibase.

Comment: I am posting this on behalf of [dev-null](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1436741/dev-null) who has posted this comment as an answer; _This is relateted to the comment of st_jeff in the preceding answer (but I have no 50 reputation to make a comment):

Another use case for failOnError: If you drop an unique constraint in oracle, than the related index gets only droped if it's newer than the constraint. So a drop index statement after dropping the constraint may result in an error or not, depending on the age of the index._